# How to use set attribute to set an element ref by using renders2 in angular?

Tags: html, angularjs

I have created a div dynamically in angular by using renderer2. Next I want to drag that div in its parent container for that purpose I want to use reference name to access it with @Child view. Means I want my div like this

```
//I want my div like below
<div #mydiv></div>
//I have achieved This untill  now
// means I want to add #mydiv 
<div ></div>
```